# Agrupar una query en función de 3 columnas

Tags: c#, sql

Muy buenas, tengo un listado de Documentos que están en en una combinación de Planta y Ubicación:

- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 1
- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 2
- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 3
- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 4
- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 5
- Documento 1 | Planta 2 | Ubicación 1
- Documento 1 | Planta 3 | Ubicación 3
- Documento 1 | Planta 3 | Ubicación 4

Todo ésto, al agruparlo por documento, me genera una única fila pero la información mostrada es equívoca ya que da la impresión de que el Documento 1 está en las 3 Plantas en las 5 Ubicaciones.

En realidad debería mostrar tan sólo 3 filas:

- Documento 1 | Planta 1, Planta 2 | Ubicación 1
- Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 2, Ubicación 5
- Documento 1 | Planta 1, Planta 3 | Ubicación 3, Ubicación 4

Aquí la query actual.

```cs
var query = from docs in  

                       (  

                                    from doc in Db.documento  

                                    join u_d in Db.ubicacion_documento on doc.id_documento equals u_d.id_documento  

                                    join ubi in Db.ubicacion on u_d.id_ubicacion equals ubi.id_ubicacion  

                                    join tip in Db.tipo on ubi.id_tipo equals tip.id_tipo  

                                    join fam in Db.familia on ubi.id_familia equals fam.id_familia  

                                    from pub in Db.publicacion  

                                    .Where(w => w.id_documento == u_d.id_documento).DefaultIfEmpty()  

                                    from cen in Db.central  

                                    .Where(w => w.id_central == pub.id_central).DefaultIfEmpty()  

                                    join val in Db.valor on doc.id_documento equals val.id_documento  

                                    select  new  

                                    {   

                                        DocId = doc.id_documento,

                                        CenId = cen == null ? 0 : cen.id_central,  

                                        LocId = ubi.id_ubicacion,  
                                        CentralName = cen == null ? String.Empty : cen.dc_nombre,  

                                        DocName = doc.dc_nombre,  
                                        DocType = tip.dc_nombre,  
                                        IdCategory = doc.id_categoria,  
                                        IdCommunity = cen == null ? 0 : cen.id_comunidadautonoma,  

                                        NameFamily = fam.dc_nombreapartado,  

                                        IdCentral = cen == null ? 0 : cen.id_central,  

                                        DocHeader = fam.dc_nombreapartado,  

                                        DocSection = fam.dc_nombreseccion,  

                                        DocDate = doc.fe_fechaactual, 

                                        Valor = val.dc_valor  

                                    }) 


                                    .Where(w => ((!filter.Community.HasValue ? true : w.IdCommunity == filter.Community.Value) && 


                                                (!filter.Category.HasValue ? true : w.IdCategory == filter.Category.Value) &&  
                                                (!filter.Central.HasValue ? true : w.IdCentral == filter.Central.Value) &&  

                                                (filter.Family == String.Empty ? true : w.NameFamily == filter.Family) &&  

                                                (filter.Section == String.Empty ? true : w.DocSection == filter.Section) &&  

                                                (filter.KeyWords == String.Empty ? true : w.Valor.ToUpper().Contains(filter.KeyWords.ToUpper()) || w.DocName.ToUpper().Contains(filter.KeyWords.ToUpper())) &&  
                                                (!filter.StartDate.HasValue ? true : w.DocDate >= filter.StartDate) &&
                                                (!filter.EndDate.HasValue ? true : w.DocDate <= filter.EndDate)

                                                )

                                        )
                            group docs by docs.DocId into docGroup
                            select docGroup;
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer lo que quiero?

Un saludo y gracias de antebrazo.

Comment: Te animo a que estudies como funciona la clausula "Group By", veras que rapido eres capaz de modificar la query para que te de el resultado deseado.

Comment: Lo que estas pidiendo no tiene ninguna logica, mas alla del como, cual es el criterio de agrupamiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agrupar por mas de una de las propiedades

[Cómo: Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb545971.aspx)

podrias usar

```
... group docs by new {docs.DocId, docs.CenId } into docGroup
```

de esta forma pones en juego los demas valores.

Igual esta raro porque no parece un agrupamiento logico el que planteas ya que parece ser un agrupamiento condicional en donde a veces unes las plantas y a veces unes las ubicaciones segun te convenga al caso.
Apunto a los condicional porque por ejemplo aqui

Documento 1 | Planta 1, Planta 2 | Ubicación 1

estas agrupando por ubicacion, pero aqui

Documento 1 | Planta 1 | Ubicación 2, Ubicación 5

estas grupando por planta, como que no tiene mucho sentido, o agrupas por uno o por otro, los group no son condicionales, quizas debas evaluar y tener dos vistas distintas de los datos, en donde agrupas por documentoy planta y otro en donde agrupes por documento y ubicacion